# Python not printing complete data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, pretty-print

So I have a Python file that contains a large set of data of nested dictionaries and lists that looks like this:

```
recipes = {
    "recipe": {
        "name": "solar_panel",
        "type": "craft",
        "ingredients": {
            "input": [
                "coal_dust",
                "glass",
                "coal_dust",
                "glass",
                "coal_dust",
                "glass",
                "electronic_circuit",
                "generator",
                "electronic_circuit"
            ],
            "output": {
                "item": "solar_panel",
                "quantity": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "recipe": {
        "name": "re_battery",
        "type": "craft",
        "ingredients": {
            "input": [
                "nothing",
                "insulated_copper_cable",
                "nothing",
                "tin",
                "redstone",
                "tin",
                "tin",
                "redstone",
                "tin"
            ],
            "output": {
                "item": "re_battery",
                "quantity": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a Python script that is this

```
import vanilla
print(vanilla.recipes)
```

One would think that is would simply print the complete data structure, but in fact it prints only the last child item (lines 23-43 in the list). I feel like I am missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the key is the same - `recipe`, so it saves only the last item in dictionary.

```
>>> {'a': 1, 'a': 2}
{'a': 2}
```

Comment: AH, that makes sense. This data was translated from xml which is how the mixup occurred.

Comment: You have to wait 10 minutes :D. Thanks for the fast answer by the way, 3 minutes is pretty amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Only one child item *exists*, since each key must be unique. If you want multiple values for a key then you must put them in a sequence such as a list or tuple.